# How to find the number of binary numbers with constraints:

Tags: binary, sequence

Given a binary digit count of n, and a maximum consecutive occurrence of "1" count of k, find the number of different possible binary numbers.

For example : `n = 3 , k = 2`.

The answer is `7`: `000`, `100`, `010`, `001`, `110`, `101`, `011`

We excluded `111` because too many consecutive `1`'s exist in it.

**How to find the number of binary numbers with those constraints ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2^n - 2^(n-k)-1` seems accurate when `n==3`, though I'm not certain

Comment: That answer does not work for n == 3 and k == 1.